# I don't understand this producer/consumer example

Tags: java, concurrency

I've been given this example in school to help me learn about producer/consumers and I can not make sense of it. I have spent all day on this and am not getting anywhere.

Can anyone tell me why it won't run?

Thanks

```
public class CarPark {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

      CarParkControl carpark = new CarParkControl(4);

      Thread arrivals = new Thread(new Arrivals(carpark));

      Thread departures = new Thread(new Departures(carpark));

      arrivals.start();
      departures.start();

   }//main
}//CarPark



class Arrivals implements Runnable {

   CarParkControl carpark;
   Arrivals(CarParkControl c) {carpark = c;}

   public void run() {
      try {
         while(true) {
            carpark.arrive();
            Time.delay(RandomGenerator.integer(0,520));
         }
      } catch (InterruptedException e){}
   }
}



class Departures implements Runnable {

   CarParkControl carpark;
   Departures(CarParkControl c) {carpark = c;}

   public void run() {
      try {
         while(true) {
            carpark.depart();
            Time.delay(RandomGenerator.integer(0,520));
         }
      } catch (InterruptedException e){}
   }
}



class CarParkControl {

   protected int spaces;
   protected int capacity;

   CarParkControl(int capacity)
   {capacity = spaces = n;}

   synchronized void arrive() throws InterruptedException {
      while (spaces==0) wait();
      --spaces;
      notify();
   }//arrive

   synchronized void depart() throws InterruptedException {
      while (spaces==capacity) wait();
      ++spaces;
      notify();
   }//depart

}//CarParkControl
```

Comment: Please post any errors you are getting.

Comment: What makes you think it won't run? This program does never print anything to the screen, so if you get a blank screen, that's normal.

Comment: Whats the `n` in the `CarParkControl` Constructor ?? There is no `n`!

Answer (score 1):

This line doesn't compile

```
 capacity = spaces = n;
```

it should be

```
 this.capacity = spaces = capacity;
```

as there is no `n`

I suggest you get the program to compile before you try to run it.